# Storing audio file into an array/stringstream C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, audio-streaming

I would like to send the contents of an audio file to another system over the network using socket. Both systems run on Windows operating system. Is there a tutorial on some way to store the audio contents into a C++ array or Stringstream datatype, so that it will be easier to send it to a different node.

I basically want to know how to extract data bytes from an audio file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to simply send the data in chunks of bytes. If you are starting with an audio file, just open it like any other binary file with something like `file = fopen(filename, "rb");` (where filename is the name of the audio file). Then enter a loop to read a chunks of bytes until you reach the end of the file. Just use something like `bytes_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), read_size, file);` where `buffer` should probably be a `char` array of at least size `read_size`, which could be, say, 1024. After each `fread`, you can make your network send call. Alternately, you could read the whole file first and then send it chunk by chunk. Your call. Either way, when you reach the end of the file, send some sort of signal that you have reached the end. The receiving system should take these chunks and call `fwrite` to create a new audio file. You can either append each chunk as it comes in or buffer it all until you reach the end and then write it all out.

Comment: Yes that should work. But i have no clue how to extract the data bytes from the audio file (ex: say a mp3 file)

Comment: `fopen` (as binary) and `fread` or any other normal file reading method. You might as well pretend the audio file is just any arbitrary binary data. For most things, you can pretend it is a text file, although some things (like `fopen`) treat binary and text differently.

Comment: that explanation was great! do i have to write to a file before playing everytime? OR is there a way to play out directly from the buffer? Any idea on this?

Comment: In the method I described, you would have to write the file to disk first. I don't think an audio player would know how to accept the input stream of raw binary data. It would have to be very intelligent. If that's what you need, you may have to look around for a specifically designed protocol for that.

Answer (score 0):

soundfile++ can be used if you have wav files only. Check the readtest and writetest demo programs here http://sig.sapp.org/doc/examples/soundfile/